# Getting maximum pixel value in grayscale image in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, mask, grayscale

After I do some image manipulation, and apply mask, I get what I want. I can clearly see on imshow result of "crop" that there's gray pixels in the middle of image.
I'm trying to get the maximum pixel value location. I've checked the crop.channels(), which returns 1.

```
    Mat mask = drawing2;
    drawContours(mask, contours, -1, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);
    Mat dist;
    distanceTransform( cannyInv, dist, CV_DIST_L2, 3 );
    normalize(dist,dist,0.0,1.0,NORM_MINMAX);
    Mat crop;
    dist.copyTo(crop, mask);
    cout << "max.. "<< *std::max_element(crop.begin<double>(),crop.end<double>()) <<endl;
```

which returns max.. 4.25593e-08

```
    for(int y = 0; y < crop.rows; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < crop.cols; x++)
        {
            if (crop.at<unsigned char>(x,y) > 0){      
                cout << "X........"<<x<<" Y......"<<y<< " = "<<crop.at<unsigned char>(x,y) <<endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

The output is:

```
X........604 Y......479 = ¿
X........607 Y......479 =   
X........610 Y......479 = ¿
```

Help me please

PD: I know that there's similar question. But this is specific problem.

Comment: every time you print values of gray images do a int casting..cout<<(int)image.at<uchar>(x,y) or cout<<(int)*ptr2pixel...

Comment: Thank you, this seems to solve the problem. (int) cast helped

Comment: However according to this I get this output:
X........625 Y......431 = 28
Which is the maximum value. But if I check manually this image, the gray high level is in the center. And the center of 640x480 is not that...

Comment: maybe I do some wrong with copyTo?

Comment: It seems like when I comment some imshow's, segmentation fault is when accessing by at(). If I leave some imshow and waitKey, I have some results. Something wrong with references I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how I solved it. A lot of time has passed. But the code that currently I have and it works is this:

```
    Mat dist=Mat::zeros(480,640, CV_8UC1);;
    distanceTransform( cannyInv, dist, CV_DIST_L2, 3 );
    Mat distNorm;
    dist.convertTo(distNorm, CV_8UC1,1,0);
    Mat result= Mat::zeros(480,640, CV_8UC1);
    distNorm.copyTo(result, mask);
    Mat tmp=Mat::zeros(480,640, CV_8UC1);
    Mat fik=Mat::zeros(480,640, CV_8UC3);
    for(int i = 0; i < result.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < result.cols; j++)
        {
            if ( result.at< uchar >( i,j ) > 0){
                uchar val = result.at< uchar >( i,j  );
                if(val>maxVal){
                    if(val>0){
                        cv::circle(tmp,cvPoint(j,i),2,255,-1);
                    }
                    maxVal=val;
                    maxX = j;
                    maxY = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that normalizing the Mat automatically converts it from uchar to double? It's very likely the data is still stored as uchars and you're reading wrong numbers from it.

Try dist.convertTo(dist, CV_64F);
Print the numbers as doubles everywhere

OR work only with uchars.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
cout << "X........"
     << x
     << " Y......"
     << y
     << " = "
     << (double) crop.at< unsigned char>(x,y) <<endl;
```